# Is there a way to automate setting credentials in DataGrip/IntelliJ for different data source?

Tags: intellij-idea, credentials, datagrip

Kinda funny question :)

I'm using some JetBrains products like **IntelliJ** and **DataGrip** as database clients.

The datasources I'm using have an annoying credentials refresh rate.
I have an alias that generate the user/pass. But its still annoying to copy+paste so much.

Is there a way to somehow automatically set the user/pass in  DataGrip/IntelliJ?

I'm using a **macOS** if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to automate this for now.
Please file a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE